# How to identify UI elements when multiple UI elements have same UI elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying UI automation using PywinAuto Lib. 
When I am trying, Multiple UI elements are  having same UI Attributes . 
Is there any way , we can alias and identify what we need.

```
ControlType: RadioButtonControl    ClassName: RadioButton    AutomationId: checkBox1    Rect: (805, 259, 855, 287)    Name:     Handle: 0x0(0)    Depth: 7    CurrentIsSelected: True

ControlType: RadioButtonControl    ClassName: RadioButton    AutomationId: checkBox1    Rect: (858, 259, 908, 287)    Name:     Handle: 0x0(0)    Depth: 7    CurrentIsSelected: False
```

As we have see , we are seeing same UI attributes for both the UI elements. One way of deal is, we can go back to UI development and change the things .

But is there any way we can do alias and identify .

```
selectButton = app1.Dialog.child_window(auto_id="checkBox1",control_type="RadioButton")
selectButton .click_input(button='left')
```

when we run , we are seeing this error .

```
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementAmbiguousError: There are 3 elements that match the criteria {'auto_id': 'checkBox1', 'control_type': 'RadioButton', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Ui automation', Window, 339012>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways:

1. Using `found_index=i` in search criteria of `child_window`.
2. Using `children()` but there is very limited number of filter criteria in 0.6.x (planned for future improvements): `class_name, control_type, content_only, title`.
3. Using `best_match` search rules from [Getting Started Guide -> How to know magic attribute names](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#how-to-know-magic-attribute-names) (previous chapters are recommended to read as well).

Comment: The Third method worked for me . Thanks alot for help :-) 
I was able to get the print_control_identifiers and use the alias name of that to do my required function